# Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ... on line

Tags: php, html, urlencode

I am a beginner programmer. Only in php.
On php, am at procedural style. Not on oop or pdo yet. Hence, you see mysqli and procedural style.

I am building a SERP with pagination. Like google, when they show you your keywords search result.

Don't mistake my thread. Not trying to prevent Sql injection as I managed to do it using prepared statements.
Learning to use `urlencode()`, `rawurlencode()`, `htmlentities()` as I'm trying to use them to prevent user's injecting unwanted html tags to breakup the html of my SERPs.

On this occasion, I am having problem using urlencode() properly.
I get this error:

> Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ... on line ...

Following are the concerned lines as I urlencode() their values so no user (keywords searcher) can inject html tags to breakup the html of my SERP:

```
$search = $_GET['search']; //Keyword(s) to search.
$col = $_GET['col']; //MySql Tbl Col to search.
$tbl = $_GET['tbl']; //MySql Tbl to search.
$max = $_GET['max']; //Max Result per page.
$page = $_GET['page']; //Serp Number.
```

The above vars contain one values each as each $_GET contains one value each, even though $_GET is a a global variable (array). So here, nothing to do with arrays or more than one value per each variable.

Issue is on this following line that comes just after the WHILE loop:
LINE 145

```
$query_string_1 = '?search=' .urlencode($search) .'&tbl=' .urlencode($tbl) .'&col=' .urlencode($col) .'&max=' .intval($max);
```

Here is the code context:

```
//ERROR REPORTING FOR DEVMODE ONLY.
ini_set('display_errors','1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);


//MYSQLI CONNECTION.
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'brute';

if(!$conn = mysqli_connect("$server","$user","$password","$database"))
{
    echo 'Mysqli Connection Error' .mysqli_connect_error($conn);
    echo 'Mysqli Connection Error Number' .mysqli_connect_errno($conn);
}

if(!mysqli_character_set_name($conn) == 'utf8mb4')
{
    echo 'Initial Character Set: ' .mysqli_character_set_name($conn);
    mysqli_set_charset("$conn",'utf8mb4');
    echo 'Current Character Set: ' .mysqli_character_set_name($conn);
}


//PAGINATION SECTION.
$search = $_GET['search']; //Keyword(s) to search.
$col = $_GET['col']; //MySql Tbl Col to search.
$tbl = $_GET['tbl']; //MySql Tbl to search.
$max = $_GET['max']; //Max Result per page.
$page = $_GET['page']; //Serp Number.


//QUERY DATABASE FOR KEYWORD COUNT.
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) From links WHERE keyword = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$query))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$search);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$row_count);
    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
    {
        echo 'Row Count: ' .$row_count; echo '<br>';    
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Record fetching failed!';
        echo 'Error: ' .mysqli_stmt_error($conn);
        echo 'Error: ' .mysqli_stmt_errno($conn);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
else
{
    echo 'Search Preparation Failed!';
}
//mysqli_close($conn);
echo '<b>'; echo __LINE__; echo '</b>'; echo '<br>';


//START KEYWORD SEARCH & OUTPUT RESULT
echo $offset = ($page*$max)-$max; echo '<br>';
echo '<b>'; echo __LINE__; echo '</b>'; echo '<br>';
$query = "SELECT id,date_and_time,domain,domain_email,ip,url,anchor,title,description,keyword,keyphrase From links WHERE keyword = ? LIMIT $offset,$max";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$query))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$search);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    if($result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt))
    {
        /*
        FOLLOWING BOTH ARE EQUAL:
        $col = mysqli_fetch_array($result) //SHORT VERSION.
        $col = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH) //LONG VERSION.
        */
        $col = mysqli_fetch_array($result); //SHORT VERSION.
        
        $id = $col['0']; //MYSQLI_NUM
        $date_and_time = $col['date_and_time']; //MYSQLI_ASSOC
        $domain = $col['2']; //MYSQLI_NUM
        $domain_email = $col['domain_email']; //MYSQLI_ASSOC
        $ip = $col['4']; //MYSQLI_NUM
        $url = $col['url']; //MYSQLI_ASSOC
        $anchor = $col['6']; //MYSQLI_NUM
        $title = $col['title']; //MYSQLI_ASSOC
        $description = $col['8']; //MYSQLI_NUM
        $keyword = $col['keyword']; //MYSQLI_ASSOC
        $keyphrase = $col['10']; //MYSQLI_NUM

        echo 'Id: ' .$id; echo '<br>';
        echo 'Date And Time: ' .$date_and_time; echo '<br>';
        echo 'Domain: ' .$domain; echo '<br>';
        echo 'Domain Email: ' .$domain_email; echo '<br>';
        echo 'Ip: ' .$ip; echo '<br>';
        echo 'Url: ' .$url; echo '<br>';
        echo 'Anchor: ' .$anchor; echo '<br>';
        echo 'Title: ' .$title; echo '<br>';
        echo 'Description: ' .$description; echo '<br>';
        echo 'Keyword: ' .$keyword; echo '<br>';
        echo 'Keyphrase: ' .$keyphrase; echo '<br>';        
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Record fetching failed!';
        echo 'Error: ' .mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        echo 'Error: ' .mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
echo '<b>'; echo __LINE__; echo '</b>'; echo '<br>';


//PAGINATION SECTION TO NUMBER THE PAGES AND LINK THEM.
$total_pages = ceil($row_count/$max);
$i = '1'; 

//$selfpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$selfpage = basename(__FILE__,''); //Echoes: url_encode_Template.php. Does not fetch the url $_GET params.
$path = rawurlencode($selfpage);
$query_string_1 = '?search=' .urlencode($search) .'&tbl=' .urlencode($tbl) .'&col=' .urlencode($col) .'&max=' .intval($max);

while($i<=$total_pages)
{
    $query_string_2 = '&page=' .intval($i);
    $url = $path .htmlentities($query_string_1) .htmlentities($query_string_2); //Full URL With $_GET params: https://localhost/Templates/url_encode_Template.php?search=keyword&tbl=links&col=keyword&max=100&page=1

    if($page == $i)
    {
        echo '<a href=' .'"' .$url .'"' .'>' .'<b>' .intval($i) .'</b>' .'</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a href=' .'"' .$url .'"' .'>' .intval($i) .'</a>';
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Frankly, the pagination page is nearly finished, had it not been for this `urlencode()` issue!
If you spot any other errors which I have not asked about it's subject due to overlooking them then kindly show me a code sample by editing my code in order to show me how I really should've coded it. (I'm talking about my usage of `urlencode()`, `rawurlencode()`, `htmlentities()` as I'm trying to use them to prevent user's injecting unwanted html tags) to breakup my SERP.

I'd appreciate it if my code is edited by someone and the correction is displayed on this thread, wherever I went wrong.

Comment: Are you sure none of your input don't have names as array eg. `name='search[]'` ..... Because one or some of your GET values is array

Comment: If you want to prevent XSS (injection of HTML or JavaScript), you can use `strip_tags()`

Comment: @ket-c, Yes, $search is not an array. $_GET['search'] gets a string value from url. url is: https://localhost/Templates/Pagination_Template.php?search=keyword&tbl=links&col=Array&max=1&page=2.

Comment: @ket-c, The issue is solved. I had two different vars named equal. Just like Rob Ructhe pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are overwriting the value of the `$col` variable that you initially populate with the 'col' parameter in the GET request with the result of your keyword search.

```php
$col = $_GET['col']; //MySql Tbl Col to search.
...
$col = mysqli_fetch_array($result); //SHORT VERSION.
```

You do not seem to be using the `col` parameter for anything, you may be able to just remove it from the query string. If you do intend to use it, simply rename the variable you are using for the query result row.

For future reference, you can encode array values into a query string using the [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function. This would simplify your code, and would have allowed you to see were the problem is in this case.

```php
// Set some test values for the parameters
$search = 'my search term';
$tbl = 'my_table_name';
$col = 'column_1';
$max = 10;

// Simulate variable being overwritten with database result
$col = [
    'id' => 123,
    'date_and_time' => '2021-06-20 09:44:00',
    'domain' => 'stackoverflow.com'
];

// Build an array of the parameters to be included in the query string
$queryParameters = [
    'search' => $search,
    'tbl' => $tbl,
    'col' => $col,
    'max' => $max
];

/*
 * Build the query string using http_build_query
 * Any array values will be represented appropriately
 * Prepend the ? to the result
 */
$query_string_1 = '?'.http_build_query($queryParameters);

echo $query_string_1.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thank you for your feed-back. You are right, I named 2 variables the same. I have now renamed the 2nd one to $cols. The error is gone.